# how send email by iPad - NSobject class

Tags: ios, ipad, email, nsobject

I have project very simply as Unity projects, and I want add a new function - sending for email application screenshot,

I try many ways to do that, but I am neebie in IOS and need your help :(

This version is working without errors, but after click button I didnt see email form

code is very short and simple - I hope someone has help me :(((

SampleViewsAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <MapKit/MKMapView.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

#import "tiDFusionMobile.h"

@interface SampleViewsAppDelegate : NSObject     <UIApplicationDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

    ///Application Window
    UIWindow *mWindow;

    UIViewController *rootViewController;

    ///Application views
    UIView    *mRender;

    tiComponent* mPlayer;
}

///IBOutlet properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *mWindow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *rootViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *mRender;


- (IBAction)openMailBtn:(id)sender;
- (void)start;
- (void)stop;

@end
```

file mm

```
#import "SampleViewsAppDelegate.h"
@implementation SampleViewsAppDelegate
@synthesize mWindow;
@synthesize mRender;
@synthesize rootViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // allocate the Component
    mPlayer = [tiComponent alloc];

    // set correct renderer
    [mPlayer setRendererType:[tiComponent TI_RENDERER_GLES2]];

    // initialze
    [mPlayer initialize:mRender];

    // start scenario
    [self start];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self stop];

    //If the player is still instanciated, it is terminated and released
    if (mPlayer)
    {
        [mPlayer terminate];    
        [mPlayer release];
        mPlayer = nil;
    }

    [mRender release];

    [mWindow release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)openMailBtn:(id)sender {

    rootViewController = (UIViewController*)
    [(SampleViewsAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] rootViewController];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    // compose
    MFMailComposeViewController* mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    //format message
    NSArray *recipientsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test@aaaa.com", nil];
    [mail setToRecipients:recipientsArray];
    NSString *emailBody = @"DSDSDSDS";
    [mail setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AAAAAA"]];

    //UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mobiletuts-logo.png"];
    //NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    //[mail addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"mobiletutsImage"];

    [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    //send
    //if (controller)
        [rootViewController presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
    [mail release];

    } else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
 }

#pragma mark - MFMailComposeController delegate

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the Drafts folder");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send the next time the user connects to email");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was nog saved or queued, possibly due to an error");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES complete:nil];
}

- (void)start
{
    if (mPlayer != nil) {
        BOOL isLoaded = [mPlayer loadScenario:@"Scenario/SampleViews_GLES1/project.dpd"];
            if (isLoaded) {
            [mPlayer playScenario];
        }       
    }
}

- (void)stop
{
    if (mPlayer && ![mPlayer isScenarioPaused]) {
        [mPlayer pauseScenario];
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Make another class of type uiviewcontroller and copy/paste all of your code except @interface line..code seems to be ok

Comment: ok so I must create new file newclass.h - copy all without mplayer parts (this is view with3d) and there catch action from button? I do it some similary but the I have problem with release mailer - ther be a info that id dosent exist in view hierarchy...

Comment: or delegate this new class in this line  [(SampleViewsAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] rootViewController];

Comment: first do it and then surprise yourself with results mate :) it will not take much time

Comment: Ok that will be first thing what I do after come back home :) thank you for your help

Comment: I created new class -> MailClassViewController (.h and .m file) and whats now? I try link button to this class but I cant drag line to this class from button,

Comment: REFER TO ANSWER BELOW.. COPY/PASTE IT,, HOPE WILL RUN PERFECT

Answer (score 0):

I GUESS YOU ARE NOT IMPORTING FRAMEWORK

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> 
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> 
@interface MailClassViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

And then the code to present the email screen:

```
- (IBAction)openMailBtn:(id)sender {

if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailCont setSubject:@"Your email"];
    [mailCont setMessageBody:[@"Your body for this message is " stringByAppendingString:@" this is awesome"] isHTML:NO];
    NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MaintenanceRequest.pdf"];

   //IF YOU DONT WANT TO ATTACH FILE THEN COMMENT IT
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
    [mailViewController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"MaintenanceRequest.pdf"];

    [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
//handle any error
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: it's not working :( Now I have two class - SampleViewsAppDelegate and MailClassViewControll - In xib I have one object Sample Views... and Window (view and toolbar).

Framework messageui is all time include :(

But button action from Toolbar is connected to SampleViewsAppDelegate function - I can't conect this to function in Mail class...

Maybe I need second object in xib for MailClasss... 
Do I need include MailClass.h in SampleViews...
Why I cant connect button with secodn class?

Comment: 3
down vote
Maybe this link would satisfy your requirement...

http://www.ericd.net/2009/04/sending-email-from-iphone-application.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/